# r3-gui can't input chinese in Pinyin

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

The **sometext** field can't input any  Chinese characters  now:

```
REBOL [
   title: "test"
]

load-gui

view [
  sometext: field
]
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, the interpreter doesn't use any IME, so no CJK, or other complex language input yet. (At least this is the case on Linux, haven't looked into the Windows implementation in details)